# My terminal only shows "Received Message:" and doesn't the actual message content for a discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I've troubleshot these bot tons and now I've reached the problem where the code runs, the discord bot comes online in the discord server and I get the "bot is ready message", but when the message is supposed to show the message content after a message is sent in a discord channel (Example: "someone says "hello" my terminal should say "Received Message: Hello")

but it doesn't.

it only says "received message:" and nothing after it no matter what.

I have discord.js v.12 downloaded and node.js downloaded, and the bot runs, but doesn't work.
Did I do something wrong in my code?:

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const TOKEN = 'I'm not gonna show you my bot token silly'; // Replace with your bot's token
const PREFIX = '!'; // You can change this to your preferred command prefix

client.once('ready', () => {
console.log(`Bot is ready!`);
});

client.on('message', (message) => { // Changed 'messageCreate' to 'message'
console.log(`Received message: ${message.content}`);
// Check if the message is from a bot or doesn't start with the prefix
if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
return; // Ignore the message
}

```
// Extract the command without the prefix
const command = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length);

// Check if the message has a number (you can customize this check)
const words = command.split(' ');
const number = words.find((word) => !isNaN(word));

// If a number is found, increment it and send the updated number
if (number !== undefined) {
  const parsedNumber = parseFloat(number);
  if (!isNaN(parsedNumber)) {
    const updatedNumber = parsedNumber + 1;
    message.channel.send(`Updated number: ${updatedNumber}`);
  }
}
```

});

client.login(TOKEN);

[Debug showing "Received message:"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcANa.png)